# Counting rows from multidimensional assiciative array

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array, export-csv

I've got this script that elaborates in many ways a multidimensional associative array and put the datas all together in a CSV file for exporting.

I need to count the rows that have the same date (`date_add`) and same order ID (`id_order`) and increment a variable for counting the rows of that singular order now lists all the items purchased but does not count the rows. Every time order change must recount the rows. I need to add a column in the CSV file that contains the count of the row of the same order (`order_id` and `date_add`).

This part below cicles the data in the array:

```
    public function fputToFile($file, $allexportfields, $object, $ae)
{
    if($allexportfields && $file && $object && $ae)
    {
        //one ready for export product
        $readyForExport = array();
        //put in correct sort order
        foreach ($allexportfields as $value)
        {
            $object = $this->processDecimalSettings($object, $ae, $value);
            $readyForExport[$value] = iconv("UTF-8", $ae->charset, $object[$value]);



        }
```

Then I elaborate the array data in many ways and then the script write in csv line by line:

```
            //write into csv line by line
        fputcsv($file, $readyForExport, $ae->delimiter, $ae->separator);
    }
}
```

I need to read the array line by line before to write into csv and if the line has the same ID "id_order" increment a variable and wite it into the array field "row_number" and put it in csv to count the lines of the order that have the same ID. Meabe we can cicle the array and count the rows that have the same "id_order" and increment this variable...

Below is a screenshot of the result of the CSV file that is produced now if you see the colum "Order no" contains the order ID. I need to count the rows that have the same id and write it in a CSV field line by line.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot of CSV file]

Comment: where in the script are doing that _"cound the rows that have the same date (date_add) and same order ID"_? I can't find it. And what part of that isn't working as expected?

Comment: Please reduce your Question and Code to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)! There is loads of unrelated code and actually nothing related. No input example, no output example, ..

Comment: excuse me I'm pretty new to stack overflow now I have reduced the code and developed my answer. thanks for being patient. there is a screenshot of the output above.